# Validation message color ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor.

I want to change the validation color message to Red. It's not working even if I change the CSS file.

My CSS file:

```
.field-validation-error {
  color: #E80C4D;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.field-validation-valid {
  display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
  border: 1px solid #E80C4D;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
  border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
  color: #E80C4D;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
  display: none;
}
```

A part of my view:

```
<td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.nom_candidat)</td>

<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nom_candidat)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.nom_candidat)
</td>
```

Comment: your CSS class must be overridden.Try to inspect that with Developer Tools or Firebug

Comment: have you tried `color: #e80c4d !important;`?

Comment: Check in the chrome debugger and see what class is applying the CSS. If you see that yours is being ignored, adding !important should help.

Comment: I tried  !important; it s not working      and  when i use debugger  i find tha  it generate   a <span......>  that i  earlier  defined with a black color

Comment: hello

i have a problem  with  overriding a css table  class

im  using  !important but it's not working 

a part of my css file

             table tr td
             {background: #F0EFE2;
              background: #FFF;
               color: #47433F;

               border-top: 1px solid #FFF;}



when  i  use   the class    "field-validation-error"   not  working  even  if  it have a red color
            
           <td>
        <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="nom_candidat"
         data-valmsg-replace="true">Le champ Nom est requis.</span>  </td>

Answer (score 13):

You can pass a style attribute as the third argument to the ValidationMessageFor method in a razor view as such:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.StudentName, "", new { @style="color:red" })
```

For a more *generic solution*, you can also run your application trigger the validation message. In Chrome, right click the validation message and inspect the element, go to the debugger window and trace the class associated with the validation error message.

Go to file *site.css* and overwrite the default validation-error message class as shown below:

```
span.field-validation-error{
     color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code to change the validation colour:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.FirstName, "", new{@class="text-danger"})
```